# Authenticating users Ionic App with Rails + Devise backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ionic-framework

Has anyone successfully implemented authentication on an Ionic application that uses a Rails application with Devise as a backend? If so, what implementation did you use to that end?

I have already tried solutions like cloudspace's angular-devise but it doesn't really play well with Devise on the server due to CORS (which I have already included the headers needed for it to work)

The current rails application allows facebook login, it would be nice if the Ionic app had that ability as well.

Comment: Just starting to look at this challenge myself. Found [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) with [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) which may be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you odlp! I will look into that. So far I have tried [angular_devise](https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise) from cloudspace and sort of got it to work even though I had issues with CORS but I don't think it is the optimal solution.

Comment: @rjricardottco how did you solve this in the end?

Comment: In the end we solved this without any library and without interacting directly with Devise. Our best solution was to implement an entirely different Token Authentication method based on this railscast: 

http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast

We did, however, use Devise's built in `user.valid_password?` method inside our API backend for user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give this cloudspace's angular-devise another shot

I have combined it with rack-cors

and it worked for me.

Another Implementation via Toke Auth is also working..
An example implementation of the rails part can be found here:
https://github.com/julianbei/authService

The Ionic Part can be found here:
https://github.com/julianbei/authService/tree/master/mobile

Its not beautiful but a working "quick and dirty" implementation

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Juiliano! I got it to work in part using rack-cors as you suggested. All I need to polish is the logout part. I'm sorry, but could you please verify the github repos you posted? They direct me to 404's. Doesn't matter if they're quick and dirty, any example is nice to follow. Thanks a lot!